# Report on attachments of emails in outlook

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, email-attachments

I am basically trying to create a report for my larger scale macro. The report will show each mail processsed and what attachments are found within the email.

I have the following code working, but does not supply me with the correct results for the .csv files only. Can anyone see any problems that I cannot?

```
    If .Attachments.Count = 0 Then
    csv_report = "NO"
    pdf_report = "NO"
    xls_report = "NO"
    End If

    If .Attachments.Count > 0 Then
    For i2 = 1 To .Attachments.Count
    If LCase(Right(.Attachments(i2).Filename, 4)) = ".csv" Then
    csv_report = "YES"
    Else
    csv_report = "NO"
    End If
    If LCase(Right(.Attachments(i2).Filename, 4)) = ".pdf" Then
    pdf_report = "YES"
    Else
    pdf_report = "NO"
    End If
    If LCase(Right(.Attachments(i2).Filename, 4)) = ".xls" Or LCase(Right(.Attachments(i2).Filename, 5)) = ".xlsx" Then
    xls_report = "YES"
    Else
    xls_report = "NO"
    End If
    Next
    End If

    Sheets("Mail Report").Activate
    Range("C65000").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = csv_report
    Range("D65000").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = pdf_report
    Range("E65000").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = xls_report

    subject_line = mail.Subject
    Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = subject_line
```

Comment: The big problem I see is that you're not using `For Each` loops.

Comment: Did you try to debug the code and see the FileName actual value?

Comment: How would I build in 'For Each' loops? I will try using msgBox to debug the code

Comment: `Dim Att as Attachment` and `For Each Att in .Attachments` with `Next Att` at the end of loop! ;) and in the loop `Att.FileName`

Comment: And you should join your If `.Attachments.Count = 0 Then` and `If .Attachments.Count > 0 Then` into :     If `.Attachments.Count <= 0 Then` and `Else`

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I will try and test your advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So by just adding 'GoTo' function I was able to answer my own query. Thank you all for leaving comments

```
    If .Attachments.Count = 0 Then
    csv_report = "NO"
    pdf_report = "NO"
    xls_report = "NO"
    End If

    If .Attachments.Count > 0 Then
    For i2 = 1 To .Attachments.Count
    If LCase(Right(.Attachments(i2).Filename, 4)) = ".csv" Then
    csv_report = "YES"
    GoTo CSVyes        'if a .csv file is found, it skips to the PDF attachment checker
    Else
    csv_report = "NO"
    End If
    Next

CSVyes:
    For i2 = 1 To .Attachments.Count
    If LCase(Right(.Attachments(i2).Filename, 4)) = ".pdf" Then
    pdf_report = "YES"
    GoTo PDFyes        'if a .pdf file is found, it skips to the XLS attachment checker
    Else
    pdf_report = "NO"
    End If
    Next

PDFyes:
    For i2 = 1 To .Attachments.Count
    If LCase(Right(.Attachments(i2).Filename, 4)) = ".xls" Or LCase(Right(.Attachments(i2).Filename, 5)) = ".xlsx" Or UCase(Right(.Attachments(i2).Filename, 4)) = ".XLS" Then
    xls_report = "YES"
    GoTo XLSyes        'if a .xls file is found, it skips to the end of the checks
    Else
    xls_report = "NO"
    End If
    Next

XLSyes:
    End If

    Sheets("Mail Report").Activate
    Range("C65000").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = csv_report
    Range("D65000").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = pdf_report
    Range("E65000").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = xls_report

    subject_line = mail.Subject
    Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = subject_line
```